# how do you map out or detect function keys in linux?

Tags: c

when you scan or get then press the function keys f1 or f2 on the terminal it will print something like"^[OP" but when you try to print it.
it either is something you can't read or, if you try to print it as a decimal it will show all the special f keys just as 27.
so can you use that behavior and identify which special character it is like some programs and turn it into something so i can add more functionalty?

or is there an easier way?

sorry, I can't put my thoughts into words properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char kl; //<-- can you store it as something different? 

int main() 
{
    printf("blah blah blah");
    printf("press f1 and clean text or press f2 for some XD's \n");
 
    kl = getchar();

    if(kl ==f1){      //<-- is there a way to differentiate be between f1 and f2
        system("clear");
        printf("cleared :P \n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    if(kl ==f2){
        system("clear");
        printf("cleared XD \n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else
        printf("fail %i",kl);
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function keys are not characters. They're function keys. Character keys are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, the space bar, and the punctuation keys. Other keys do not generate printable characters.

Comment: Run the program. Hit f1. See what getchar returns. (It might return a multi-character sequence.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Chen how do i check multi-character sequence properly?
be cause this is what i get �
1519218051
�
1519218051
�
1519218051
�
1519218051

Comment: 1519218051 doesn't even fit in a `char`. How could you be getting that in `kl`?